# Why am I getting a type mismatch error 13?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

Why am I getting a type mismatch error with this code?

`"=COUNTIF($A$2:$H$301," * "&L2&" * ")"`

I am trying to count the number of instances the name in cell "L2" shows up in the range "A2:H301". As you can see it needs to be a partial match. Image below for a helpful visual.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: remove the spaces between the `"` and the `*` all four of them unless you string starts and ends with a space it will not find a match.  Probably not your problem, but something that will give you false negatives.  with vba you will need to double the `"`:  `"=COUNTIF($A$2:$H$301,""*""&L2&""*"")"`

Comment: Hassan, I added some context. Scott, thank you, I thought I had already tried that but apparently not. One of those situations where I was going around in circles! Thank you!